# How to use output in bash to assign it as variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to assign the output of user's input value of AD Domain to last line "/opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix" and not able to perform the same.

```
#!/bin/bash
domainjoin-cli join
# AD Domain: <User's Input>
# Username:  <User's Input>

/opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix <input value>
```

Tried 'read' and 'output'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yya8H.png)

I need to include the test.com to /opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix

Comment: Where does `"<UserDomainPrefix input value>"` come from? All you show is `domainjoin-cli join`??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what ever user inputs for AD Domain, I need to use it "/opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix"  <user's input from AD Domain>

Comment: Why not just pass the `UserDomainPrefix` and `username` as parameters to your script and then access them as `"$1"` and `"$2"`? e.g. `/opt/pbis/bin/config "$1" "$2"`? So if the user runs `./yourscript somedomain john` your last line becomes `/opt/pbis/bin/config somedomain john` -- is that what you need??

Comment: Thank you! It works. Though there is a different error msg.

Comment: when I run the script this is the error msg but still the script run successfully. 
 
test.sh: 2: test.sh: : Permission denied.  #!/bin/bash  "$1"  domainjoin-cli join 
 /opt/pbis/bin/config UserDomainPrefix "$1"  /opt/pbis/bin/config 
 AssumeDefaultDomain true  /opt/pbis/bin/config LoginShellTemplate 
 /bin/bash  /opt/pbis/bin/config HomeDirTemplate %H/%U  /opt/pbis/bin/config 
 RequireMembershipOf "$1"\domain^users  /opt/pbis/bin/update-dns

Comment: `"Permission Denied"` generally means you did not make the script executable, e.g. `chmod +x yourscript.sh`. Then `./yourscript.sh somedomain somename`. Or just `bash yourscript.sh somedomain somename`.

Comment: It has the required permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `read` as you said

```
read iUSERNAME
```

Then you can use it with the prefix `$` as below

```
printf '%s\n' "$iUSERNAME"
```